# Using pandas to perform time delta from 2 "hh:mm:ss XX" columns in Microsoft Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file with a column named `StartTime` having `hh:mm:ss XX` data and the cells are in `h:mm:ss AM/FM' custom format. For example,

```
ID    StartTime
1     12:00:00 PM
2      1:00:00 PM
3      2:00:00 PM
```

I used the following code to read the file

```
df = pd.read_excel('./mydata.xls',
                   sheet_name='Sheet1',
                   converters={'StartTime' : str},
                   )
```

`df` shows

```
ID  StartTime
1   12:00:00
2    1:00:00
3    2:00:00
```

Is it a bug or how do you overcome this? Thanks.

[Update: 7-Dec-2018]

I guess I may have made changes to the Excel file that made it weird.  I created another Excel file and present here (I could not attach an Excel file here, and it is not safe too):

[image]

I created the following code to test:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./Book1.xlsx',
                   sheet_name='Sheet1',
                   converters={'StartTime': str,
                               'EndTime': str                   
                              }
                  )

df['Hours1'] = pd.NaT
df['Hours2'] = pd.NaT

print(df,'\n')

df.loc[~df.StartTime.isnull() & ~df.EndTime.isnull(),
       'Hours1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.EndTime) - pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime)

df['Hours2'] = pd.to_datetime(df.EndTime) - pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime)
print(df)
```

The outputs are

```
   ID StartTime   EndTime Hours1 Hours2
0   0  11:00:00  12:00:00    NaT    NaT
1   1  12:00:00  13:00:00    NaT    NaT
2   2  13:00:00  14:00:00    NaT    NaT
3   3       NaN       NaN    NaT    NaT
4   4  14:00:00       NaN    NaT    NaT 

   ID StartTime   EndTime         Hours1   Hours2
0   0  11:00:00  12:00:00  3600000000000 01:00:00
1   1  12:00:00  13:00:00  3600000000000 01:00:00
2   2  13:00:00  14:00:00  3600000000000 01:00:00
3   3       NaN       NaN            NaT      NaT
4   4  14:00:00       NaN            NaT      NaT
```

Now the question has become: "Using pandas to perform time delta from 2 "hh:mm:ss XX" columns in Microsoft Excel".  I have changed the title of the question too. Thank you for those who replied and tried it out.

The question is 
**How to represent the time value to hour instead of microseconds?**

Comment: Are you sure this is the output that you get? When I try to reproduce I get correct times, ie `13:00` and `14:00` (pandas 0.23.4 and numpy 1.15.1)

Comment: My excel file is with xls extension, and was created by system, not Microsoft Excel. Let me create a simple one and upload. Thank you to look into it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `StartTime` column is formated as text in your file.

Have you tried reading it with `parse_dates` along with a parser function specified via the `date_parser` parameter? Should work similar to [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) although the docs don't list the above options explicitly [despite them being available](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/io/excel.py#L283).

Like so:

```
pd.read_excel(r'./mydata.xls',
              parse_dates=['StartTime'],
              date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%I:%M:%S %p').time())
```

---

**Given the update**:

```
pd.read_excel(r'./mydata.xls', parse_dates=['StartTime', 'EndTime'])
(df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']).dt.seconds//3600
```

alternatively

```
# '//' is available since pandas v0.23.4, otherwise use '/' and round
(df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime'])//pd.Timedelta(1, 'h')
```

both resulting in the same

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64
```